# Can you run python as a windowed program?

Tags: python, user-interface, window

Hello fellow python users, I bring forth a question that I have been wondering for a while. I love python, and have made many programs with it.  Now what I want to do is (or know how to do) make a python program, but run it in a window with buttons that you click on instead of typing in numbers to elect things.  I would like to just know weather or not I can do this, and if I can, please tell me where to go to learn how. Ok, it's not for the iPhone, sorry that I wasn't clear on that, and I didn't realize that iPhone was one of the tags.

Comment: This is tagged "iphone" but I see no mention of it in the text. You should remove this tag if it does not apply. Also, your question would be better worded asking about a Python "GUI", not a Python "window". Python already runs in a window when it is in the console.

Comment: @Marcin, I was capable of making that edit, too. However, it is best for the OP to do so to be sure of his intent.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If he wants to work with the iphone, then the text of the question is singularly inapt.

Comment: @Marcin I agree, but you don't know for sure what his intentions are, so let's let him make the edit. That's why I left him the comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Or, let's not leave it to him, because nothing will get done. He's written only one comprehensible question out of seven posted.

Comment: @Marcin and if the question really *was* about the iPhone, there are three answers that do not apply.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I find myself unmoved by the plight of someone who only gets answers relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can make a program with a GUI in Python.  See the Python docs:

- [Graphic User Interface FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html)

Tkinter, wxWidgets, and Qt are a few of the most popular UI toolkits for Python.

Comment: Seeing there is iPhone in tags I guess question is regarding iOS...

Comment: Right, but he never mentioned it anywhere in the question.... and that tag was just removed.

Comment: I guess that the best starting point to obtain a GUI, without getting mad with the GuI programming, is the EasyGui module. Small, simple, useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, the library is called `tkinter`.

Comment: This is just one of many UI toolkits for python.

Comment: It is the one that comes with the standard python installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many GUI libraries to choose from, but I like Tkinter because it's easy and there's nothing to install (it comes with Python).

But some people prefer wxPython or others, such as PyQT. You'll have to decide which you like, or just go with Tkinter if you don't want to go through the trouble of installing libraries just to try them out.